# Cannot add fingerprint login to non-standard account in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, uac, fingerprint, biometrics

Tl;dr:I have successfully added a fingerprint to an administrative account, but it won't work with the built-in one. Bug?

When attempting to add fingerprint login with Windows Hello under the built-in administrative account in Windows 10, the Windows Hello window errors out. I have added a fingerprint login with Windows 10 on a standard user account on my box, and it works fine. UAC works okay with it and its all good. However, when I switch to the admin account and attempt to add a fingerprint, it won't let me continue. I have the option, I've set a PIN, and it says Setup, but when I click it the window pops up and closes immediately. I haven't been able to find anyone having this same issue so far. Restarts, driver updates, uninstall and reinstall reader/driver, Anyone else run into this? Can anyone confirm if this is a known issue or that it's something going on locally on my box?

Running Win10 on HP desktop with Lenovo fingerprint reader, driver is TouchChip Fingerprint Coprocessor (WBF advanced mode).

Comment: What you describe is intended, Windows Hello and setting up a pin, both require you to use a user created account linked to a Microsoft Account, and the default Administrator account cannot be linked to a Microsoft Account

Comment: The standard user account is not linked to a Microsoft account, so that cannot be true. Plus that's not what I'm asking about, I want local a admin. fingerprint stored which I can pull from through UAC.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "non-standard" account.  You asked if it was a bug, if being unable to use Windows Hello with the built-in Administrator account was a bug, and my comment indicates it isn't a bug because you are not intended to do that.  I have lots of Windows 10 devices, none of them, allow a Pin or Windows Hello on the default account.

Answer (score 1):

My experience : Dell XPS13 out of the box

First time start up, created standard account (that I was not allowed to call administrator), skipped "Hello" process, followed installation.

Logged on standard account : could access Hello process without trouble, could add pin, fingerprint, ...

Made administrator account visible (cmd, net user Administrator /active:yes)

Logged on as administrator (no password).
Go to hello setup : could add password or pin with no problem, but fingerprint remained greyed.

So to confirm this is an intended windows feature (really don't know why !!).

I've not been able to find anywhere a way to modify this.

Comment: Thank you so much with sharing this experience. I did exactly the same thing with XPS15. Same problem; can't assign fingerprint to built-in Administrator account but works for other accounts. It looks like some windows restriction or a bug. What a shame ! **Have you found a workaround ?** 

(The worst answer comes from microsoft where they talk about corrupted database, can they even try what they talk about: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/fingerprint-cannot-setup-on-win10s-administrator/370c0a36-2f95-40db-bc71-be0ee53e238a )

Answer (score 0):

this setting is specially greyed out when machine is AD domain member. To enable pin login you need to add to registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System]
"AllowDomainPINLogon"=dword:00000001
```